# Handle exceptions with decorator on properties in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I have a property that has an assertion to check if a value is of type str.

To catch this assertionError I have created a decorator according to the examples I have found online.

Decorator:

```
def catch_assertionerror(function):
    def handle_problems(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError:
            # log_error(err.args[0])
            print "error caught"
    return handle_problems
```

Property:

```
@catch_assertionerror
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    assert isinstance(value, str), "This value should be a string"
    self._name = name
```

Setting the name property:

```
self.name = self.parse_name_from_xml()
```

When I run this code, there is no error shown, so I guess it is caught, but on the other hand, the error message is not printed to the screen.

Then I tried a more simple example I found on Stachoverflow:

```
def handleError(function):
    def handleProblems():
        try:
            function()
        except Exception:
            print "Oh noes"
    return handleProblems


@handleError
def example():
    raise Exception("Boom!")
```

This also handled the error but did not print the error message to the screen.

Could someone explain to me what I am missing here?

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you are calling the function

Comment: I've just tried your "more simple example" in an interactive python session, and it works as expected. How are you running this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your latter example works for me, but your main problem lies in that you're not wrapping a function with `catch_assertionerror` in

```
@catch_assertionerror
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    assert isinstance(value, str), "This value should be a string"
    self._name = name
```

but a [`descriptor`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). To make matters worse, you return a function instead, not a new descriptor wrapping the original. Now when you assign to `name` attribute you just replace your wrapper function with the assigned value.

Step by step, using your original class definition:

```
class X(object):

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @catch_assertionerror
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        assert isinstance(value, str), "This value should be a string"
        self._name = value

>>> x = X()
>>> x.name
<unbound method X.handle_problems>
>>> x.__dict__
{}
>>> x.name = 2
>>> x.name
2
>>> x.__dict__
{'name': 2}
```

What you must do is wrap the method function instead and then pass it to the descriptor handling decorator:

```
class X(object):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    @catch_assertionerror
    def name(self, value):
        assert isinstance(value, str), "This value should be a string"
        self._name = value
```

and so:

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in name
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute '_name'
>>> x.name = 2
error caught
>>> x.name = "asdf"
>>> x.name
'asdf'
```

---

In the future consider using `functools.wraps` and `functools.update_wrapper`. Without them your classes and functions are harder to inspect, because your wrappers will hide the original:

```
>>> @catch_assertionerror
... def this_name_should_show(): pass
... 
>>> this_name_should_show
<function handle_problems at 0x7fd3d69e22a8>
```

Defining your decorator this way:

```
def catch_assertionerror(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def handle_problems(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return handle_problems
```

will preserve the original function's information:

```
>>> @catch_assertionerror
... def this_name_should_show(): pass
... 
>>> this_name_should_show
<function this_name_should_show at 0x7fd3d69e21b8>
```

It would have also indicated to you in your case that there's a problem:

```
# When trying to define the class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in X
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in catch_assertionerror
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__module__'
```